# Memory Leaks when we are using NSXmlParser in auto Release pool

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

```
- (void)main
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    self.workingArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.descriptionString = [NSMutableString string];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:dataToParse] autorelease];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    if (![self isCancelled])
    {
        // notify our AppDelegate that the parsing is complete
        [self.delegate didFinishParsing:self.workingArray];
    }

    self.workingArray = nil;
    self.descriptionString = nil;
    self.dataToParse = nil;
    [pool drain];
}
```

in this code when we `[parser parse]` is called in this line the memory leaks problem is happened.